# Unix Display Which Filesystem

Tags: bash, unix, filesystems

How do I display which type of filesystem I am currently browsing (i.e. ext3, ext4, or xfs)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the mount command

$mount

lists all mounted file systems

Answer (score 2):

How about:

`df -T . | awk '{ print $2 }'`

Comment: Didn't work for me (Fedora 14) - just gave 'type' and then the blocksize of the last partition

Comment: doesn't work on mac, fyi

Comment: I get better output with df -T -P | awk  '{ print $1"\t"$2 }'

Comment: @Linker3000, pipe that into `column -t` for prettier output.